# I called the network once, but in test it gets caught twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress

Here is my test code

```
context('event page', () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.visit('/event');
    });

    it('create banner', () => {
        cy.intercept('GET', '/events').as('events');
        cy.wait('@events').then(intercept => {
            console.log(intercept);
            cy.get('[data-cy=cuma-event-item]').should('have.length', intercept.response.body.length);
        });
    });
});
```

here is my react code..

```
const Container: React.FC<EventPageProps> = ({ eventSSR }) => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState<EventType[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEvents = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetchEventList();
                setEvents(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        fetchEvents();
    }, []);

    return <Items events={events.length > 2 ? events : eventSSR} />;
};
```

[image: cypress results]

I called once, but why do I get two in the test result?

Besides, always one request fails and I get an error in cy.wait.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

multiple possibilities, thinking of some here.

is it an HTTP OPTIONS request, followed by HTTP POST?

I am not that good with cypress. from your screenshot, has the first request been finished? because you're updating the state inside the effect. from [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks):

> **Does useEffect run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

you don't have any rule defined in the second argument of `useEffect` (the empty array). see [skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

maybe this can point you into a direction.

Comment: In actual execution, the network runs once.

But in cypress it is running twice.